# Пунктирный ProgressBar

Tags: java, android, progress-bar

Нужно создать пунктирную шкалу прогресса, как показано на картинке:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Количество шагов может быть динамическим, ширина между шагами предполагается постоянной.

Были попытки использования библиотеки из ответа: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41974072/how-to-get-dashed-horizontal-progressbar-in-android

Но такой подход не обеспечивает должной динамичности. Какие ещё варианты существуют?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немного непонятно что значит`не обеспечивает должной динамичности`. Если речь идет о кол-ве шагов, то в той библиотеке которую вы привели в качестве примера есть метод:

```
setNumDots()
```

я думаю данный метод отвечает за кол-во промежутков. Так же есть и [такая библиотека](https://github.com/carlosmuvi/SegmentedProgressBar). Ее подключение можно сделать по аналогии с той что вы уже пробовали. Вот метод который установит кол-во промежутков:

```
// number of segments in your bar
segmentedProgressBar.setSegmentCount(7);
```

в качестве номера я допускаю вы будете передавать переменную. Так же вот есть [еще одна библиотека](https://github.com/rayzone107/SegmentedProgressBar) где тоже есть метод для установки кол-ва шагов:

```
SegmentedProgressBar spb = findViewById(R.id.segmented_progress_bar);
spb.setDivisions(10); \\ Integer value for total number of divisions
```

В каждой из приведенных библиотек можно самостоятельно установить кол-во шагов, либо я не понял что значит динамичность, хотя вами было сказано - `Количество шагов может быть динамическим`

Comment: Смысл в том, что количество шагов не меняет ширину самого шага, то есть чем больше шагов, тем шире должен быть объект. Если бы число шагов было бы статичным, можно было бы рассчитать все единицы. Но здесь динамичность

Comment: но по логике если шагов будет очень много то они просто не поместятся в ширину экрана, ведь ширина не меняется )

Comment: Да, в этом то и проблема...

Comment: давайте подойдем с другой стороны :) какая логика у данного решения будет? это скроллится будет или как? если вы немного меня посвятите в то что планируется я попытаюсь вам помочь :)

Comment: Обычный прогресс-бар, но с дырками) С другими элементами он никак не связан, просто висит и показывает прогресс...

Comment: прогресс чего? вообще если я правильно понимаю при изменяемом кол-ве промежутков и при статичной ширине, ширина промежутка будет меняться) это было бы логично)